# Powershell XML encoding

Tags: sql, xml, powershell, encoding

I have a script that executes a stored procedure on a SQL Server which returns XML. I then have a function to to format the XML in powershell so it is readable. When i open the XML in Chrome i get this error:

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 149 at column 27: Encoding error
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

I think I may need to encode it in UTF8 but I am unsure where to do it in my code. Any help to rectify the error or how to do the encoding is appreciated.

Here is the Powershell that I run to get the XML file:

```
function Format-XML {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param ([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,Mandatory=$true)][string]$xmlcontent)
  $xmldoc = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlDocument
  $xmldoc.LoadXml($xmlcontent)
  $sw = New-Object System.IO.StringWriter
  $writer = New-Object System.Xml.XmlTextwriter($sw)
  $writer.Formatting = [System.XML.Formatting]::Indented
  $xmldoc.WriteContentTo($writer)
  $sw.ToString()
}


$Date = Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd_HHmm" 
$File = "C:\Temp\MyFile"+$Date+".xml"

$Query = "EXEC dbo.usp_MyProc"

$resultRow = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $Query -database MyDatabase -ServerInstance MyServer 


Format-xml $resultRow['results'] | Set-Content -Path $File -Force
```

Comment: Try appending `-Encoding UTF8` to your last line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment "Try appending -Encoding UTF8 to your last line" from Martin Brandi worked